# Sort Python list containing both letters and numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list `directory_contents` that contains:

**['Folder 1', 'Folder 10', 'Folder 11', 'Folder 12', 'Folder 13', 'Folder 14', 'Folder 15', 'Folder 16', 'Folder 17', 'Folder 18', 'Folder 19', 'Folder 2', 'Folder 20', 'Folder 21', 'Folder 22', 'Folder 23', 'Folder 24', 'Folder 25', 'Folder 26', 'Folder 27', 'Folder 28', 'Folder 29', 'Folder 3', 'Folder 30', 'Folder 4', 'Folder 5', 'Folder 6', 'Folder 7', 'Folder 8', 'Folder 9']**

And I just need to sort it so that it looks like basically like what windows or any operating system would show it like:

[image]

So that it would be:

['Folder 1', 'Folder 2', 'Folder 3', 'Folder 4', and so on...

I tried `directory_contents.sort()` and `directory_contents = sorted(directory_contents)` but both did not work.

Comment: Read about the `key` parameter for the `sort`/`sorted` functions. Then write a function which extracts the number from the folder name and use that.

Comment: Since the dictionary_contents values are all strings, it'll sort it alphabetically. I'd say to use something like split() to get an array of just the numbers, and working from there.

Comment: is there a way to do it quickly without custom code?

Answer (score 2):

sort by the number:

```
  directory_contents = ['Folder 1', 'Folder 10', 'Folder 11', 'Folder 12', 'Folder 13', 'Folder 14', 'Folder 15', 'Folder 16', 'Folder 17', 'Folder 18', 'Folder 19', 'Folder 2', 'Folder 20', 'Folder 21', 'Folder 22', 'Folder 23', 'Folder 24', 'Folder 25', 'Folder 26', 'Folder 27', 'Folder 28', 'Folder 29', 'Folder 3', 'Folder 30', 'Folder 4', 'Folder 5', 'Folder 6', 'Folder 7', 'Folder 8', 'Folder 9']
  directory_contents.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.strip('Folder')))
```

Also this is a bit faster:

```
timeit("""directory_contents = ['Folder 1', 'Folder 10', 'Folder 11', 'Folder 12', 'Folder 13', 'Folder 14', 'Folder 15', 'Folder 16', 'Folder 17', 'Folder 18', 'Folder 19', 'Folder 2', 'Folder 20', 'Folder 21', 'Folder 22', 'Folder 23', 'Folder 24', 'Folder 25', 'Folder 26', 'Folder 27', 'Folder 28', 'Folder 29', 'Folder 3', 'Folder 30', 'Folder 4', 'Folder 5', 'Folder 6', 'Folder 7', 'Folder 8', 'Folder 9']; directory_contents.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.strip('Folder')))""", number=1000)
0.06238140000000669
timeit("""directory_contents = ['Folder 1', 'Folder 10', 'Folder 11', 'Folder 12', 'Folder 13', 'Folder 14', 'Folder 15', 'Folder 16', 'Folder 17', 'Folder 18', 'Folder 19', 'Folder 2', 'Folder 20', 'Folder 21', 'Folder 22', 'Folder 23', 'Folder 24', 'Folder 25', 'Folder 26', 'Folder 27', 'Folder 28', 'Folder 29', 'Folder 3', 'Folder 30', 'Folder 4', 'Folder 5', 'Folder 6', 'Folder 7', 'Folder 8', 'Folder 9']; directory_contents.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.split(' ')[1]))""", number=1000)
0.08448790000001338
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sort()` method and pass `key` parameter to it:-

```
directory_contents.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.split(' ')[1]))
```

Now if you print `directory_contents` you will get your desired output